# Bidirectional infinite scrolling with FlatList?

Tags: react-native

Has anyone had experience doing bidirectional infinite scrolling with `FlatList` (or any other component)?

My use case is I have a calendar month view that I want to be able to swipe left and right to get the next and previous month.

`FlatList` with `onEndReached` and `onEndReachedThreshold` works great for one direction, but there is no similar thing for the start.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `onScroll` props on the Flatlist for that: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll

```
        onScroll={({
                nativeEvent: {
                    contentInset: { bottom, left, right, top },
                    contentOffset: { x, y },
                    contentSize: { height: contentHeight, width: contentWidth },
                    layoutMeasurement: { height, width },
                    zoomScale,
                },
            }) => {
                if ( y <= your_start_threshold) {
                     // Do what you need to do on start reached
                }
            }}
```

Only problem is that React native doesn't support bidirectional `FlatList` on Android. This means that when you add items to the start of your list, it will jump to the top instead of keeping the current items in view (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25239).

(iOs does have a `maintainVisibleContentPosition` props)